# Minitest Controller Error : :Template::Error: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, minitest

When I run my tests I get this error:

```
  1) Error:
CategoriesControllerTest#test_new:
ActionView::Template::Error: No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/Javi/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs201504
29-7044-qg60v0json
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__20669174_54234900'
    test/controllers/categories_controller_test.rb:6:in `test_new'

4 runs, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Here is my application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TestingBasics</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

I created a categories/new.html.erb file and saved it

This is my controller test that is failing:

```
require "test_helper"

class CategoriesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def test_new
    get :new 
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

EDIT:: 
Here is my controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @category = Category.new
    end

end
```

I also have the following in my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :categories

end
```

I have a new.html.erb on my views but its not working...

Does anyone know what is happening? It looks like there is a problem with my application file picking up json? I am new to testing so not sure what this is.

Answer (score 0):

@coderwannabe2 your view should be named 'test_new.html.erb' not 'new.html.erb'
The error is stating that it cannot find a template matching 'test_new' which is true. Your template right now is 'new' so change 'new.html.erb' to 'test_new.html.erb' and you should have magick!

You should always remember that if in your controller you have inside the class

```
def view_one
end
def view_two
end
```

then your views must match the method name so in this case you would have

```
view_one.html.erb
view_two.html.erb
```

This is really watered down explanation but it should help get your mind around it all and how the method names relate to views and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up changing my testcontroller action/method to be 'new' rather than making my controller test_new since that would be weird. But this definitely helped me solve it, now I get it!

Comment: @coderwannabe2 that is great and I am glad you got it fixed! Just an fyi if you accept something as answer you should +1 it to ;)
Keep at it once everything starts clicking you will begin liking ROR a lot.

Comment: hmm nvm this didn't work since my test methods needs to start with test or else the test suite doesn't pick them up it seems. But i rename my view to be test_new.html.erb then that will appear to the user on the url path and I don't want that. There must be a better solution...

Comment: @coderwannabe2 you can have controller routes that the views do nothing, it processes and then passes control to a new view. I am not sure what you are trying to do now. Some additional information would be most helpful.

Comment: what does "you can have controller routes that the views do nothing" mean? I don't understand. I updated the post with my controller code and my routes, I have a new action and a new.html.erb view. How can I test that in my test_new is my question? I am getting the error above still.

Comment: I have reposted the problem with more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958215/actionviewtemplateerror-no-such-file-or-directory-unlink-internal-c-us     can you help please?