# ActionView::Template::Error: No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/Javi/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs201504 29-7844-j0j83vjson

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, execjs

When I run my tests, the controller one fails claiming that it can't find any views/categories/new.html.erb file. This is the failure:

```
$ rake test:controllers
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Run options: --seed 30439

# Running:

E

Finished in 2.486100s, 0.4022 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
CategoriesControllerTest#test_new:
ActionView::Template::Error: No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/Javi/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs201504
29-7768-ntpk2ujson
    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__379261802_30194400'
    test/controllers/categories_controller_test.rb:6:in `test_new'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

This is my full test stacktrace. I think maybe its a problem with the execjs or something having to do with how my javascript is loading on my application. This app is almost basic toy app with nothing on it that I just started.

```
$ BACKTRACE=1 rake test:controllers
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Run options: --seed 11579

# Running:

E

Finished in 2.514007s, 0.3978 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
CategoriesControllerTest#test_new:
ActionView::Template::Error: No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/Javi/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs201504
29-6372-sgswcqjson
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:173:in `unlink'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:173:in `ensure in e
xec_runtime'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:173:in `exec_runtim
e'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:14:in `initialize'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/runtime.rb:44:in `new'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/runtime.rb:44:in `compile'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/execjs-2.5.2/lib/execjs/module.rb:27:in `compile'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1/lib/coffee_script.rb:50:in `context'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/coffee-script-2.4.1/lib/coffee_script.rb:78:in `compile'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:21:in
`block in call'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/cache.rb:85:in `fetch'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:20:in
`call'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_pr
ocessor'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block i
n call_processors'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse
_each'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_pr
ocessors'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:87:in `load_asset_by_ur
i'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:157:in `fetch_asset_fro
m_dependency_cache'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `bloc
k in initialize'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yiel
d'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load
'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_pr
ocessor'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block i
n call_processors'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse
_each'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_pr
ocessors'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:87:in `load_asset_by_ur
i'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:45:in `block in load'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:157:in `fetch_asset_fro
m_dependency_cache'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:38:in `load'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `bloc
k in initialize'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yiel
d'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load
'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:63:in `find_asset'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.0.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:89:in `[]'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:123:in `ass
et_digest_path'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:76:in `comp
ute_asset_path'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:13
5:in `asset_path'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:91:in `asse
t_path'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb:24
5:in `javascript_path'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:61
:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:59
:in `map'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb:59
:in `javascript_include_tag'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:148:in `jav
ascript_include_tag'
    c:/Users/Javi/desktop/rails_projects/minitest_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_ap
plication_html_erb__741928323_31430316'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in r
ender'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in
`block in instrument'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrument
er.rb:20:in `instrument'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in
`instrument'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument
'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:
66:in `render_with_layout'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:
52:in `render_template'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:
14:in `render'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `re
nder_template'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `re
nder'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_t
emplate'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:i
n `_render_template'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_
body'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in
 `render_to_body'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in
 `render_to_body'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `re
nder'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in
 `render'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb
:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12
:in `block in ms'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12
:in `ms'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb
:44:in `block in render'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb
:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtim
e.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb
:43:in `render'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb
:10:in `default_render'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb
:5:in `send_action'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `proces
s_action'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in
 `process_action'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `bl
ock in process_action'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `cal
l'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `cal
l'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `blo
ck (2 levels) in compile'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `cal
l'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `cal
l'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run
_callbacks'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_ru
n_process_action_callbacks'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_
callbacks'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `pr
ocess_action'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `p
rocess_action'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb
:32:in `block in process_action'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in
`block in instrument'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrument
er.rb:20:in `instrument'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in
`instrument'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb
:30:in `process_action'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:
250:in `process_action'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtim
e.rb:18:in `process_action'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `proces
s'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:632:in `pro
cess'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:65:in `proc
ess'
    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:508:in `get
'
    c:/Users/Javi/desktop/rails_projects/minitest_app/test/controllers/categories_controller_test.rb:6:in `test_new'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

As you can see on this line:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/Javi/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs201504
29-7216-9o5jujjson
```

Is a bit weird, I am not sure what it means. I went to the C:/Users/Javi directory and was unable to find any AppData folder... Not sure why that is even a thing at it's not on my system.

This is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '2.7.1'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem "minitest-rails"
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

This is my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>MinitestApp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

The error message says that the error occurs at line 6:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

So this leads me to believe my javascript is not loading properly...

I am using Minitest, here is my controller test:

```
require "test_helper"

class CategoriesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

    def test_new
        get :new
        assert_response :success
    end

end
```

I have also created a new.html.erb view that is mostly blank except for some dummy text:

```
This is my new file! #This is inside my views/categories/new.html.erb
```

Here is my controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

end
```

When I turn on rails server and I navigate to my root/categories/new route I get the following error message:

```
Errno::ENOENT in Categories#new
Showing c:/Users/Javi/desktop/rails_projects/testing_basics/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/Javi/AppData/Local/Temp/execjs20150429-4112-xc20tpjson
Rails.root: c:/Users/Javi/desktop/rails_projects/testing_basics
```

Can someone please help me figure this out? I have been stuck on this for 2 full days. I have tried downgrading execjs gem version but still get the error. I have also restarted from scratch and get the same error at the same place. Not sure what else to do now...

Comment: I can't help but I will give you my advice - use Linux.  If you are just getting started, there are cloud IDEs like Cloud9 which remove all of the mystery of Linux and include a lot of other benefits.

Comment: have you install nodejs?

Comment: I have installed it previously a few months ago when messing around with angular.js How can I check if I have node installed?

Answer (score 1):

Removing  //= require_tree from application JS will fix this issue.Or you can install Node.js and use instead of the JavaScript runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I got thing working by changing this line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

To this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Seems like this might lead to problems down the road though, lets hope not. Does anyone know what changing 'application' to 'default' does to my rails app?

Comment: Changing 'application' to 'default' means you have changed appliaction.js with default.js and default.js file will not be present in your path,that is why you are not seeing issue.But this is not the fix,you have to either remove //require_tree or use NodeJs.